# With $u = x^3$ and $v=\arcsin(x)$, prove $\frac{du}{dv}=3\sqrt{u(u^{1/3}-u)}$

Tags: derivatives

> If $u=x^3$ and $v=\arcsin(x)$, prove that $$\frac{du}{dv}=3\sqrt{u(u^{1/3}-u)}$$

I have tried $$\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{\frac{dv}{dx}}$$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: "To prove" questions mean that the answer is *steps leading to* the equation asked to be proven.

Comment: Your first step looks good – where do you get stuck?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u=x^3 \implies \dfrac{du}{dx}=3x^2$$

$$v=\sin^{-1}x \implies \dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

\begin{align}
\dfrac{du}{dv}&=\dfrac{\frac{du}{dx}}{\frac{dv}{dx}}\\&=\dfrac{(3x^2)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}\\&=3x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}\\&=3\sqrt{x^4-x^6}\\&=3\sqrt{x^3(x-x^3)}\\&=3\sqrt{u(u^{1/3}-u)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$3\sqrt{u(u^{\frac13}-1)}=3\sqrt{x^3(x-x^3)}=3x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2\text{  and  } \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$